# How create a For to Hours in Twig

Tags: php, symfony, twig

Hi i'm new in Symfony and Twig, so i have the question:
How can i create something like this in twig?

```
for ($i = 0; $ <10; $i++) {
   //do something
}
```

My problem is, I've to populate a Hour option jumping 5 in 5 minutes like:

```
<option> 00:05 </option>
<option> 00:10 </option>
<option> 00:15 </option>
<option> 00:20 </option>
```

And when arrive to 60 minutes add 1 hour...

Thanks for suggestions...

Comment: pls read documentation: https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/for.html

Answer (score 0):

In Twig, You can create a Variable (even an Array). In this case you may want to create an Array of Strings and then Loop through it like below. Note that this is just a very rudimentary way of doing it.

```
        <label for="split-time">Please choose a 5-Minute Split Time:</label><br />
        <select id="split-time">
           {% set minutes = ["00", "05", "10", "15", "20", "25", "30", "35", "40", "45", "50", "55"]  %}
           {% for split in minutes %}
               <option value="00:{{ split }}">00:{{ split }}</option>
           {% endfor %}
        </select>
```

On the other hand, you may just want do some prep-work in your Controller like below. Assuming your Action is timeAction(); you can do this inside the Time action:

```
        public function timeAction() {
            // GENERATE THE TIME INDICES:
            $timeIndices    = array();
            for($i=0; $i < 60; $i+=5){
                $val = $i;
                if($i < 10){
                    $val = "0" . $i;
                }
                $timeIndices[] = $val;
            }
            return $this->render('YourBundle:ControllerName:time.html.twig', array(
                'timeIndices'   => $timeIndices
            ));
        }
```

Then in Twig, You could do just:

```
        <label for="split-time">Please choose a 5-Minute Split Time:</label><br />
        <select id="split-time">
           {% for timeIndex in timeIndices %}
               <option value="00:{{ timeIndex }}">00:{{ timeIndex }}</option>
           {% endfor %}
        </select>
```

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way is:

```
{% for minutes in range(0, 24 * 60 - 1, 5) %}
    <option>{{ (minutes * 60)|date('H:i', false) }}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

You can change output format as you wish. For instance, if you need to have a step size of 15 minutes and display 'am/pm', you can use following variant:

```
{% for minutes in range(0, 24 * 60 - 1, 15) %}
    <option>{{ (minutes * 60)|date('h:i a', false) }}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

So you'll get options like these:

```
<option>12:00 am</option>
<option>12:15 am</option>
<option>12:35 am</option>
```

This is a very flexible and easy solution.

Moreover, you can have a difference in seconds (or minutes) as option's value, like this:

```
{% for minutes in range(0, 24 * 60 - 1, 5) %}
    <option value="{{ minutes * 60 }}">{{ (minutes * 60)|date('H:i', false) }}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score -2):

This is how I would do it.

```
<select name="time">
    {% set i = 0 %}
    {% for j in 0..12 %}
        <option value={{ i }} >{{ i }}</option>
        {% set i = i + 5 %}
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Adjust the numbering according to your requirements.